# EF Core Include On Collection Class Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I keep getting errors like

`: The property expression 'met => {from TrM x in met select [x].Tm}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.`

I have a class structure of

```
 public class Tr: BaseModel
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public List<Trm> Mets { get; set; } = new List<Trm>();

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Test TestDef { get; set; }
}



    public class Trm: BaseModel
{

    public Tm tm { get; set; }
}


public class Tm: BaseModel
{

    [JsonIgnore]
    public T TestDef { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to say when loading Tr load all Trm and include Tm when loading.

I have tried the following

```
 var results = await _dbContext.Tr
                .Include(tr => tr.Mets ).ThenInclude(met => met.Select(x=> x.tm))
                .Include(tr => tr.TestDef)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
            return results;
```

How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `Select` for `Include` in Ef Core. You should drill down to load related data by using `ThenInclude`.

```
   var results = await _dbContext.Tr
    .Include(tr => tr.Mets )
         .ThenInclude(met => met.tm)
    .Include(tr => tr.TestDef)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here is the offical [documentation](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/staging/querying/related-data.html#including-multiple-levels).

Comment: I actually discovered this but there is a bug in my version of the Rosyln complier which doesn't actually auto complete the properties for the .ThenInclude so it through me off :( :(

Comment: the above way ddid not work from, insted I used
    .ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath: tr =>tr.TestDef)

Comment: @LmC you are right but this only appears when you use same aliases in Where/Include/ThenInclude. Using different aliases brings correct property names suggestions for me.